# Questions about singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have some questions about singularities that should be rather simple to clear up. First of all, is a zero of a function a removable singularity? So if I have f(z)=$e^{z}-1$ is z=0 a removable singularity?

Can a function have multiple singularities? (I assume yes but since we're here we might as well be safe)

Now say I have something like $sin(1/z)$. When $z=0$ what type of singularity do we have? Do we have a pole (1/z clearly goes to $\infty$)? Do we have a removable singularity (the sin is bounded between 1 and -1)? Or is it essential (if it were to be neither since sin can be rewritten with the Euler formulas and isn't bounded by Liouville's theorem)

Comment: $z = 0$ is not a singularity of $e^z-1$...

Answer (score 1):

**Poles**

A singularity is a point where things go bad at an isolated point in the domain of an analytic function. For example, $\frac1z$ has a pole at $z=0$. The function is not defined at $z=0$ and the function grows arbitrarily large as $z$ gets close to $0$. A pole at $z=a$ can be removed with multiplication by $(z-a)^n$ for a large enough integer $n$.

**Removable Singularities**

Certain kinds of bad can be remedied. For example, at $z=1$ in
$$
f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}
$$
Technically, $f(1)$ is not defined since its evaluation requires division by $0$. However, everywhere but at $z=1$ we have $f(z)=z+1$. This singularity is removable since we can define $f(1)=2$ and then $f(z)=z+1$ everywhere.

**Essential Singularities**

Essential Singularities are those that are neither removable nor poles. If $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=a$, then so does $1/f$. The [Great Picard Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%27s_great_theorem) describes the behavior of functions near an essential singularity. That is, the function takes on every complex value except at most one in all neighborhoods of the singularity.

---

Points from the question:

Unless there is a problem in the definition of an analytic function, I would not call a zero a singularity. For example, $z^2/z$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, which happens to be a zero of the function.

Functions can have an infinite number of singularities, for example, $\cot(\pi z)$ has a pole at every integer.

The property that $|\sin(x)|\le1$ is only valid for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In $\mathbb{C}$, $\sin(x)$ can take on any value. In fact, $\sin(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a singularity at $p$ of an holomorphic map $f: U\backslash \{p\} \to \mathbb C$.

If you can define an holomorphic map $f : U \to \mathbb C$ the singularity is said *removable*. Here $e^z - 1$ is already defined in $0$, so it's not a singularity at all !

After, it's not clear what do you mean by "multiple singularities". The function could have one singularity with multiplicity $d > 1$ for example the map $z \mapsto z^{-d}$ or several singularities, like $z \mapsto \frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$.

Finally a function is said *meromorphic* on $U$ if $f$ is holomorphic on $U \backslash A$ where $A$ is discrete, and for each $a \in A$ there is a neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$ and an integer $k_a$ such that $U \cap A = a$ and 
$z^{k_a}f$ is holomorphic on $U_a$.

If you have a singularity, you have 3 options :

1) the singularity is removable

2) we have $\lim\limits_{z \to p}|f(z)| = + \infty$ ($\Rightarrow$ the function is meromorphic)

3) the singularity is essential.

Now, since $\sin(1/z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ we have  $$\sin(1/z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}(2n+1)!}$$
which is clearly a non-removable singularity, and non holomorphic if multiplyed by any $z^k$. Then, $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ has an essential singularity at the origin.